# Position Button 8px from the right

Tags: css

I'm building a menu with 100% width - and I'm trying to position one button on the left side and one on the right side.

[This is what I have](http://jsfiddle.net/zPkH8/), however as you can see the button is not placed 8px from the right.

How would I go about it? Thanks!

```
#options-buttons {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.okay_button
{
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  right: 8px;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/RIIV8.png');
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 68px;
  height: 34px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: none;
}

.okay_button:hover
{
  background-position: 0 -34px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use float right and right;  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPkH8/4/)

```
.okay_button
{ 
  top: 3px;
  right: 8px;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/RIIV8.png');
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 68px;
  height: 34px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zPkH8/2/) (I replaced the background with text for demo purposes):

You are mixing float, display, and position incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` on your `.okay_button`, since that will force it to be relative to its container, not its otherwise normal position.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zPkH8/3/

```
.okay_button
{
  position: absolute;

  ...

}
```